# Converting EDI to Xml

Tags: .net, xml, parsing, edi

I have not done any work with edi in almost 10 years and also the technologies available to parse it may have changed.
Are there any example code routines (actual code, not products) available to parse edi strings?
I know I could parse it but I bet some good routines could help me get started faster.

BTW, I don't know yet what the other party will be sending. I think maybe it will be x12 but of the document type I do not know yet, so I'm just looking for general maybe low level applicable to anything type code at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for free software start with codeplex

http://x12parser.codeplex.com/

Comment: awesum. this is exactly what I wanted.